# How to change color of a BarGraphItem without re-creating?

Tags: python, colors, bar-chart, pyqtgraph

I am using the BarGraphItem from pyqtgraph to create a bar chart and want to change the appearance of a bar if it is clicked/selected but I cannot find out how to do this.

The bar chart is displayed fine and I can set the original color but I cannot find any reference anywhere to how I can change the color (in my case to reflect the selected state)

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Overload `PlotWidget` and `BarGraphItem`. Check if the `QMouseEvent` position of your `PlotWidget.mousePressEvent` is inside one of your bars:

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MyBarGraphItem(pg.BarGraphItem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setAttr(self, **opts):
        if 'x' in opts:
            self.x = opts['x']
        if 'height' in opts:
            self.height = opts['height']
        if 'width' in opts:
            self.width = opts['width']
        if 'brushes' in opts:
            self.brushes = opts['brushes']
        super().setOpts(**opts)

class MyPlot(pg.PlotWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bars = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        pos = self.getPlotItem().vb.mapSceneToView(ev.pos())
        if self.bars is not None:
            for i,_ in enumerate(self.bars.x):
                if self.bars.x[i]-self.bars.width/2 < pos.x() < self.bars.x[i]+self.bars.width/2\
                        and 0 < pos.y() < self.bars.height[i]:
                    b = self.bars.brushes
                    b[i] = pg.QtGui.QColor(255,255,255)
                    self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
                    print('clicked on bar '+str(i))
                    ev.accept()
        super().mousePressEvent(ev)

    def addBars(self, bars):
        self.bars = bars
        self.addItem(bars)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = pg.mkQApp()

    plot = MyPlot()

    bars = MyBarGraphItem()
    bars.setAttr(brushes=[pg.hsvColor(float(x) / 5) for x in range(5)], x=[i for i in range(5)], height=[1,5,2,4,3], width=0.5)

    plot.addBars(bars)

    plot.show()

    app.exec()
```